# Postgresql starting failed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I was connected with remote postgres-9.3 by pgAdmin III. After close pgAdmin i try to connect on another day with the same db.

```
 /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 status
 dead but pid file exists
```

```
service postgresql-9.3 start     FAIL
```

In pgstartup.log file i have:

```
This account is currently not available
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             89.70.224.82/32         md5
```

Operating system on server is CentOS. I don't know unfortunately how postgres was installed on the server because someone else done that.
What i can do with this?

Comment: A hint - the contents of `pg_hba.conf` is irrelevant.

Comment: The error message suggests that the `postgres` user doesn't have a valid shell. Which leads to the question of what is the operating system and how you installed postgres on it.

Comment: I have edited post by add information about Operating system

Comment: See the contents of /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3. Find out as which user postgresql is being started (probably postgres). Check if that user exists in /etc/passwd.

Comment: I have found this line in /etc/passwd: 
postgres:x:26:26:PostgreSQL Server:/var/lib/pgsql:/sbin/nologin

Answer (score 3):

The solution is reset your PostgreSQL logs

```
[root@user /]#/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_resetxlog -f /usr/pgsql-9.3/data/
```

after executing above command  display "Transaction log reset"

and then restart PostgreSQL server

```
[root@user /]# /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 restart

Stopping postgresql-9.3 service:                           [FAILED]

Starting postgresql-9.3 service:                           [  OK  ]

[root@qa /]# /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 status
 (pid  3003) is running...
```

after checking your pgadmin

Comment: Your first command says "You must run pg_resetxlog as the PostgreSQL superuser."

Answer (score 0):

Try to start cluster using native postgres utility.
Assuming you have CentOS 6.6 and postgresql 9.4

`sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_ctl -D <YOUR_DATA_DIR> start`

You will get some reasonable output. 
Then try to start postgres in single user mode

`sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgres --single -D <YOUR_DATA_DIR> -P -d 1`

Beware that resetting xlogs will cause some data lost.
I also recommend to read this article http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/11/when-postgres-will-not-start.html